# Angular JS update model from dom

Tags: dom, angularjs

I've seen heaps of questions about this, and all of them seem to be solved by either calling [$scope.$apply()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply), [$scope.$digest()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest), or by triggering the change() method on the input. But I can't seem to get it working with any of those methods. In this fiddle, I can type a name into the box and get the model value to update as I type. But when I click the link, to set the input name to a certain value, I want the model name to update. What do I need to do?

The reason I'm trying to do this is I want to be able to refresh my angular model when a user autofills the form, using the browser autofill or LastPass or similar. Surely there's some angular command to refresh the model from the DOM?

http://jsfiddle.net/PXCUq/

```
$(function () {
    $('#setFirstName').click(function () {
        $('input.firstname').val('Test Name');
        angular.element($('input.firstname')[0]).scope().$apply();
        // Model still not updated
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing it this way instead?:  `<a ng-click="input.firstname = 'Test Name'">set first name</a>`?

Comment: I'm looking for a workaround to make browser form autofills work. This is a simpler way of getting the value to change without user input, to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Get the scope, then change the ng-model property:

```
$('#setFirstName').click(function() {
    var scope = angular.element($('input').get(0)).scope()
    scope.firstname = 'Test Name';
    scope.$apply();
});
```

You can come up with a better jQuery selector.  I was only focusing on the Angular part.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/XysvF/).

Comment: This would sort of work... So to refresh the model from the dom, I'd need to run through every element, get its ng-model attribute, and set the model value like that. Is there really no way to do this within Angular?

Comment: You don't need to go through every element to get its scope. You just get scope once. Like: `scope = angular.element($('div[ng-view] > *)[0]).scope()`